# Select method expression using lambda syntax ignoring overloads

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, lambda, expression-trees

I currently use the following extension method in order to select a method:

```
    public static MethodInfo GetMethod<TType>(this TType type, 
                           Expression<Action<TType>> methodSelector) 
                           where TType : class
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)methodSelector.Body).Method;
    }
```

This is called like this:

```
this.GetMethod(x => x.MyMethod(null,null))
```

It doesn't matter to me which method I'm selecting, I'm simply using this as way to get the method name in a strongly-typed way. Is there a way that I can still select the method using the lambda syntax but not specify any arguments?

I.e.

```
 this.GetMethod(x => x.MyMethod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, but with the added cost of having to specify signatures for methods which take parameters. I couldn't work out how to get those automatically.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static MethodInfo GetMethod<TType, TSignature>(this TType type, Expression<Func<TType, TSignature>> methodSelector) where TType : class
    {
        var argument = ((MethodCallExpression)((UnaryExpression)methodSelector.Body).Operand).Arguments[2];
        return ((ConstantExpression)argument).Value as MethodInfo;
    }

    public static MethodInfo GetMethod<TType>(this TType type, Expression<Func<TType, Action>> methodSelector) where TType : class
    {
        return GetMethod<TType, Action>(type, methodSelector);
    }
}
```

Tested with this simple example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void RunTest()
    {
        var m = new MyClass().GetMethod(x => x.Test);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", m);

        m = new MyClass().GetMethod<MyClass, Action<int>>(x => x.Test2);
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", m);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
    }

    public void Test2(int a)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's certainly a step in the right direction. Some of my methods have 4 or 5 parameters so I'm keeping my fingers crossed that there might be a way to get round this.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a few different things but can't hit on anything that will make type inference pick up the return type of the lambda for use in the Expression. I have now sadly exhausted my minimal Expression skills :)